# How would I use the python split() method, but in a way that it splits at multiple characters and not just that specific string that is inputed?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the `split()` method to split at a list or string of one character.

Here's the program I was trying out before I came here:

```py
def strcontains(a, str):
  a_match = [True for match in a if match in str]

  return True in a_match

def splitall(chars, text):
  full = []
    for char in chars:
      if char in text:
        x = text.split(char)
        if strcontains([i for i in chars], x):
          x = splitall(chars, ''.join(x))
        full.extend(x)

    return full



print(splitall('dfs','hello i like dogs cuz they so fluffy'))
```

What I expect:

```
['hello I like ', 'og', ' cuz they ', 'o ', 'lu', '', 'y']
```

What I get:

```
['hello i like ', 'ogs cuz they so fluffy', 'hello i like dogs cuz they so ', 'lu', '', 'y', 'hello i like dog', ' cuz they ', 'o fluffy']
```

How would I combine those list items to get what I expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I much prefer a pure pythonic way of solving a question like this, without having to import a big module (such as re). Below, I made a function to do this:

```py
def splits(string, chars):
    indexes = []
    for index, char in enumerate(string):
        if char in chars:
            indexes.append(index)
    indexes.append(len(string))

    splits = []
    pindex = 0
    for index in indexes:
        newsect = string[pindex:index]
        for char in chars:
            newsect = newsect.replace(char, '')
        splits.append(newsect)
        pindex = index
    return splits
```

Breaking it down, there are 2 main parts of the function. In the first, it goes through and identifies where all the various target characters are, and marks their positions in a list, for chopping up in part 2.

In part 2, we start by creating a list, where all the substrings will go. The main loop works by adding the string in between the previous index (pindex), and the current index (indexes being the positions of the target characters determined in part 1).

For example, if you had a string of: "Bob and I went to the park," and the target was "n," then pindex starts as 0, and the first index of 'n' is at 6, so the function adds `string[0:6]` (`'Bob an'`) to the final list. Then, pindex is now 6, and the next index of n is at 13, so `string[6:13]` is then added.

A couple extra lines, and why they exist:

`indexes.append(len(string))`: this adds the end of the string as an index. Otherwise, in part 2, after it reaches the last index of the target characters, it will quit, and the part from the last character to the end is ignored

`for char in chars:  newsect = newsect.replace(char, '')`: As you may have noticed in the example, the target characters were still included in the substrings, (`'Bob an' vs` 'Bob a'`), because all that was done was slicing. This line is to get rid of any target characters left over after slicing

> Note: If the end letter of the string is a target, an unnecessarily large amount of blank strings (`''`) will be added to the end of the list. You can remove these with a line such as: `if newsect=='': continue`, before the `splits.append(newsect)`

Comment: yeah that works too

Answer (score 2):

Use re.split as explained in this article

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-multiple-characters-from-string/

Comment: This is a comment, not answer

Comment: thanks! works exactly as I envisioned